# Testing React API with Jest

Tags: reactjs, api, unit-testing, jestjs

In the project I'm working on the back-end connection is done via restclient.js file, which, when simplified, looks like so:

```
const someFunctionality = {
    method1: () => fetch(...)
}

const someOtherFunctionality = {
    method2: () => Promise(...)
}

const yetAnotherFunctionality = {
    method3: () => { return environment.something() }
}

const environment = {
    something: () => document.querySelector(...).getAttribute(...)
}
```

When writing unit tests for a component that uses the restclient, I tried mocking it like so:

```
jest.mock('../restclient', () => ({
    __esModule: true,
    restclient: { yetAnotherFunctionality: {method3: jest.fn(() => {return 'some value'}) } }
}));
```

However, the tests fail at this very point:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'yetAnotherFunctionality' of undefined
> const id = restclient.yetAnotherFunctionality.method3()
```

What am I missing? What would be correct way to mock such an API with Jest?

Comment: Could you please include some more info ?

Comment: What kind of info?